# Установка фокуса и каретки программно и безопасность

Tags: javascript

Вступает ли программная установка фокуса и каретки на поле `contenteditable=true` в конфликт из-за политики безопасности в какой либо из топовых ОС?

Если подробней, то есть текстовое `contenteditable=true` поле и есть полускрытое такое же поле. Для того чтобы синхронизировать с помощью соккетов два клиента, приходится сначала писать в буферное текстовое поле, затем отсылать написанное на сервер, который обновит у всех клиентов основные текстовые поля. Для вставки в основное текстовое поле, на него нужно устанавливать программно каретку, а когда идет ввод,то кареткунужно программно ворачивать в буферное поле.

Но возник вопрос, а вдруг существует система или браузер, в котором нельзя такое проделать из-за политики безопасности. Сталкивался кто-то с подобным?

Answer (score 1):

Безопасность тут не причем. Современные браузеры запускают сайты в песочницах и OC вообще нет дела до того, что происходит внутри. Использование скрытых полей вообщем обычная практика.

**UDP** Зачем вы переносите коретку из поля в поле? При отправке дублируйте данные в видимом и не видимом поле, если необходимо. При загрузке данных пишите сразу в оба (опять же если необходимо).

Comment: Ну я могу копипаст отследить и зафигачить его в скрытое поле,а там  может оказаться личная информация. Это тоже нормально для современных браузеров?

Comment: В скрытом поле не может оказаться личной информации,если пользователь лично не ввел ее в видимое поле. А если ввел, то в чем разница? Вы и так и так получили личную информацию.